# ¿Como convertir cadena de text a object Json?

Tags: vb.net

Hola buenos días a todos, estoy tratando de convertir una cadena de datos que me da como respuesta una url, a la cual eh llamado str1, esta es la respuesta status=0&is_banned=0&balance=0&rate=0.139&user=12345, lo que quiero es convertirla a un object de Json para poder sacar la información por separado, es decir así:
status=0
is_banned=0
balance=0`introducir el código aquí`
rate=0.139
user=12345
eh tratado con esto pero no logro nada.

```
**Dim obj As var = JSON.parse(Data.str1)**
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Comment: hola buen día, revisando lo que mencionas, no es posible desde esa cadena generar un json, ya que no lleva una estructura valida para eso, lo que tendrías que hacer en este caso es generarlo manual, tal vez haciendo un Split por &, obtienes cada item y lo separas por  = , y asignando el parámetro manual

Comment: Creo que me explique mal, lo que yo deseo realmente es obtener de la cadena "status=0&is_banned=0&balance=0&rate=0.139&user=12345" solo los valores, por ejemplo de status=0 solo deseo obtener el 0. La opcion que tu me das Eduardo Jaramillo Licea, es buena pero no cumple con lo que yo deseo. mil disculpa.

Comment: es lo que te comento, opción como tal para obtener los valores en una cadena de ese tipo no las hay, tienes que hacerlo manual,

Comment: Eduardo Jaramillo Licea gracias, ya lo solucione con lo siguiente espero y le sirva a alguien. Status = Mid(str1, 8, 1)    '
                        Is_banned = Mid(str1, 20, 1)
                        Balanc = Mid(str1, 30, 1)

Answer (score 0):

La solución que planteas, usando MID(str,i,l), es peligrosa cuando la longitud de la cadena es variable, imagina que el valor de RATE en vez de 3 decimales, te llega con 2 o 4 decimales o si los elementos de la cadena pueden tambien variar o su orden. Considero la mejor opción la de Eduardo Jamarillo, con un doble SPLIT...

```
    Dim cadena As String = "status=0&is_banned=0&balance=0&rate=0.139&user=12345"

    Dim elementos As String() = cadena.Split("&") ' Arreglo de elementos

    For Each elemento In elementos
        Dim valor As String() = elemento.Split("=") ' Separamos el valor
        Select Case valor(0) 'Asignamos los valores , independientemente del orden en el que lleguen...
            Case "status"
                status = valor(1)
            Case "is_banned"
                ...
        End Select
    Next
```